# How do I create image scaling effect in nested flexbox column layout?

Tags: css, flexbox

**Backstory:** The following `flexbox` based layout works as expected.  As I shrink the width of the browser all three images scale down at equal rates.  If you run the code snippet please click the `Full page` link and scale the browser to see this simple effect.

```css
.flexParent {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.flexChildOne {
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.flexChildOne img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.flexInterior {
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flexChildTwo {
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.flexChildTwo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.flexChildThree {
    width: 400px;
}

.flexChildThree img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
    
    <div class="flexChildOne"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lzSH.jpg"></div>

    <div class="flexInterior">
        <div class="flexChildTwo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q4Q7.jpg"></div>
        <div class="flexChildThree"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBC6.jpg"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

However when I add `flex-direction: column;` to the `flexInterior` class the effect doesn't work as needed.  The left image scales as before but the two images inside `flexInterior` remain static.  Their right edges get progressively cut off as the browser shrinks instead of scaling.  This is because of the line `overflow: hidden;` which is needed in the original row layout to cause the scaling effect but creates this new cutting problem in the column layout version.

**Question:** In the column layout how do I make the images scale similar to the row layout?  This is a simplified example.  In the actual version I'm using media queries to display either the column or row version depending on the width of the browser.

```css
.flexParent {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

.flexChildOne {
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.flexChildOne img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.flexInterior {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Only line that was changed */
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flexChildTwo {
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}

.flexChildTwo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


.flexChildThree {
    width: 400px;
}

.flexChildThree img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
    
    <div class="flexChildOne"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lzSH.jpg"></div>

    <div class="flexInterior">
        <div class="flexChildTwo"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Q4Q7.jpg"></div>
        <div class="flexChildThree"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vBC6.jpg"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child elements of `.flexInterior` are wider than their parent

Remove the width from `.flexChildTwo` and `.flexChildThree` and add it to `.flexInterior`

```
.flexInterior {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/IanJohnson/pen/QzqggE?editors=1100

You will also want to get rid of the `margin-right` when its in the column layout

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I added `width: 400px` to the parent and in my media query version added `width: auto` to the children and it worked perfectly.  I stared at that for 2 hours and couldn't determine a solution.  Now it's obvious!